# Select everything except one column in ARRAY_AGG + STRUCT in BigQuery

Tags: arrays, struct, google-bigquery

I'm currently using **ARRAY_AGG + STRUCT** to nest all the fields in my table under one column and yes, it works. The problem is that the solution I'm using is **not scalable**. I'd like to select all the fields except for one in my STRUCT but I've no idea on how to do this. Here the sample:

```
SELECT
Col1,  
ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Col2,
      Col3,
      Col4,
      Col5,
      Col6,
      Col7)) OVER (PARTITION BY Col3, Col4, Col5)
FROM
  Source
```

And here what I'd like to have:

```
 SELECT
    Col1,  
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(* EXCEPT(Col1))) OVER (PARTITION BY Col3, Col4, Col5)
    FROM
      Source
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardsql
select col1,  
  array_agg((select as struct * except(col1) from unnest([t]))) 
    over(partition by col3, col4, col5)
from source t
```